# How do I sync 2 objects based on the change of a checkbox?

Tags: angularjs

I'm at the very beginning stage of learning Angularjs, so please bear with me for asking this stupid question. I basically want to do it the right way from the start instead of just making it work.

Anyhow, I have 1 Order Checkout form which contains 2 sets of addresses: shipping and billing. I have a checkbox which says "Shipping address is the same as billing address", which if checked should sync the 2 addresses.

My approach is that 2 addresses will be treated as 2 objects, and if the checkbox is checked then I will have something like scope.shippingAddress = scope.billingAddress.

I wonder if the above is a good way to do it?

Also, what is a good way to trigger the above syncing upon checkbox change? Should I use ng-checked or perhaps should I use $watch?

Comment: I would go for ng-change http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.checkbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a watch:

```
$scope.$watch('shippingIsSameAsBilling', function(value) {
  if(value) {
    $scope.shippingAddress = $scope.billingAddress;
  } else {
    $scope.shippingAddress = angular.copy($scope.shippingAddress);
  }
});
```

You need to "unsync" the two addresses if the user unchecks the checkbox again by assigning each its own object (using `angular.copy`).

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aawTTXQGp8FI4vtTodJE?p=preview) for a working example.

Note that you'll be sending two identical addresses to your back-end. Are you sure you want to do it that way?

Comment: Thank you. Yes because sometimes the address maynot be identical. I know it's possible to sync on the backend side instead but in this case I think it's more consistent this way. If you don't mind me asking another very stupid question: I assume this piece of code should be put in either a controller or a directive right?

Comment: Yes, inside a controller

Comment: This is working great. However there seems to be a minor issue. If I click the checkbox first before anything (in your sample plunker code), then billing and shipping will not be synced when I start entering info into shipping. I think the reason is that at first $scope.shippingAddress will be undefined and thus we are not actually referencing to a real object with the call "$scope.shippingAddress = $scope.billingAddress". Is there any fix you would suggest?

Comment: Ah, yes then the watch will just assign `undefined` to shippingAddress and it's not synced. You need to initialize billingAddress in your controller. I've updated the plunker.